Devuelve null al capturar parámetros de la URL en el ModelForm django
Con el objetivo de poner un valor inicial a un field que venga de la url, estoy intentando capturar el parámetro id_modulo de la url en my ModelForm con kwars.get, pero devuelve None. Este parámetro sí lo recupera en el método get_context_data de mi vista.
Por lo que he visto en otro mensaje, sería correcto, pero no me funciona.
url.py
path('paramTablas/alta/<int:id_modulo>/', ParamTablasCreateView.as_view(), name='paramTablas_alta'),

view.py
class ParamTablasCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermisosRequeridosMixin, CreateView):
    model = ParamTablas
    form_class = ParamTablasForm
    template_name = 'Mi template'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        "... Variables de contexto"

        print (self.kwargs.get('id_modulo')) # Recupera el parámetro correctamente
        return context

forms.py
class ParamTablasForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id_modulo = kwargs.get('id_modulo') # Obtenemos el parámetro de la url
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        print(id_modulo) # Imprime None
        
        self.fields['cod_modulo'].initial = id_modulo # No contiene el parámetro de entrada
        self.fields['cod_tabla'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = ParamTablas
        fields = '__all__'

Estoy iniciándome en django y necesitaría ayuda para resolver este tema.
Muchas gracias de antemano y saludos.

La respuesta de @Anthonyx82 realiza lo que buscaba, gracias.
Pero el nuevo argumento adicional me daba problemas después, con los métodos dispatch. Investigando, se me ha ocurrido volver a quitar el argumento, una vez almacenado, ya que no necesito que siga teniéndolo y ha funcionado correctamente.
Así quedaría el forms.py:
class ParamTablasForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id_modulo = kwargs.get('id_modulo') # Obtenemos el parámetro de la url
        kwargs.pop('id_modulo') # Eliminamos el argumento una vez almacenado, para evitar error en el dispatch.

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.fields['cod_modulo'].initial = id_modulo # Asignamos el valor inicial
        self.fields['cod_tabla'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = ParamTablas
        fields = '__all__'



El problema esta siendo en que el parámetro id_modulo no lo estas pasando hasta el formulario. En tu vista, estás recuperando bien el parámetro de la URL utilizando self.kwargs.get('id_modulo'), pero no estás pasando este valor al formulario en ninguna parte.
Para solucionar esto, necesitas pasar el valor de id_modulo al formulario como un argumento adicional al crear una instancia del formulario en tu vista:
class ParamTablasCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermisosRequeridosMixin, CreateView):
    model = ParamTablas
    form_class = ParamTablasForm
    template_name = 'Mi template'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Recupera el parámetro correctamente
        context['id_modulo'] = self.kwargs.get('id_modulo')
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        # Pasar el valor de id_modulo al formulario
        kwargs['id_modulo'] = self.kwargs.get('id_modulo')
        return kwargs


con el método get_form_kwargs, ya recupera el parámetro, que es lo que buscaba, pero al ir a un método dispatch, devuelve el error TypeError: BaseModelForm.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_modulo'. Parece que el nuevo parámetro añadido no lo espera. No sé si puedo dar por finalizada esta pregunta y abrir una nueva. Gracias.
